# How can a neutral atom, e.g., a rubidium atom, be accelerated to a high speed?

Tags: atomic-physics, experimental-technique, accelerator-physics

I have this question because I am studying quantum friction for my PhD project.

Quantum friction could refer to the frictional force induced by the electromagnetic field fluctuations on a neutral particle (but polarizable) when it passes above a surface with some speed. To actually observe it, one needs to prepare the particle to be moving quite close to the surface (within micrometer or nanometer range) with a very high velocity (a substantial fraction of the speed of light). The distance is not a big challenge here. Because current experiments can easily reach the required distance. But is it possible to accelerate the neutral particle to a large speed? If so, what is the maximum achievable velocity, say, for a Rb atom? (I am using the example of a Rb atom, because it has a relatively large electric polarizability which could enhance the quantum friction to some extent. Other neutral atoms are good too.)

Answer (score 4):

One accelerates the Rb as an ion beam, using standard ion accelerators. Now the problem is how to get neutrals from the ion beam. This is achieved through either a charge exchange canal with a background gas, or a thin foil. As the ions pass through, electrons can be exchanged between the background gas (or foil) and the ions. Note that this can go both ways, so the result is a variety of charge states of Rb coming out, including neutrals. While there are many papers in the literature on charge exchange, [Comsol](https://www.comsol.com/blogs/modeling-beam-neutralization-with-a-charge-exchange-cell/) has a nice blog entry to give you an overview, even showing the electrostatic separator downstream of the charge exchange to deflect the charged species.

I will note that the recent literature on 'neutralization' focuses on either modern high-current ion implant systems, where electrons are injected into the beam to make it quasi-neutral to reduce Coulomb repulsion (expanding the beam), or for neutral particle beams to pump fusion reactors. So look back to the 1960's or 70's for charge exchange canals.

Comment: Thank you, Jon! This is very helpful!